# Consider one input field to 90 percent and display another 10 % automatically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two input value, the two value should be equal to 100%, one input contain 90% and the other should contain 10%, the value should be auto calculated based on input change in any field.

```js
function checkValue (type) {
  var no = 0;
  var percent = 0;
  var otherPercent = 0;
  if (type === 'ninetyPercent') {
    no = document.getElementById('ninetyPercent').value;
    percent = parseInt(no) / 90;
    otherPercent = (parseFloat(percent.toFixed(2)) - parseInt(no))
    document.getElementById('tenPercent').value = otherPercent;
  } else {
    no = document.getElementById('tenPercent').value;
    percent = parseInt(no) / 10;
    otherPercent = (parseFloat(percent.toFixed(2)) + parseInt(no));
    document.getElementById('ninetyPercent').value = otherPercent;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>This should consider as 90% for the input</label>
<input type="number" id="ninetyPercent" onInput="checkValue('ninetyPercent')" placeholder="90%">
<br>
<br>
<label>This should consider as 10% for the input</label>
<input type="number" id="tenPercent" onInput="checkValue('tenPercent')" placeholder="10%">
```

The general Idea is if we insert 90 in first input, the second input should auto fill 10, likewise if we input 10 in second input, the first input should auto fill 90 and so on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these percents or just numbers? I understand the `90%` and `10%` part, but what does `900` and `100` have to do with this?

Comment: 900 should be consider as 90% and the other 10 percent is 100 (maybe), it's my general idea only

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? https://jsbin.com/zitapibuku/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @bassxzero almost correct, but the idea is if you enter 100000 (1 lakh) in first place, 1 lakh should be considered as 90%, and the other 10 percent (10 thousand or 90 thousand.. not sure xD) should auto field in second input.. and likewise if we enter second input first then it should be considered as 10% and the other 90% should display in the first input field

Comment: Have you checked my answer? If you have any questions, feel free to comment the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#foo input');

function getOtherInput(changedInput) {
  return [...inputs].find(input => input !== changedInput);
}

foo.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  const changedInput = event.target;
  const definingValue = Number(changedInput.value);
  const definingPercentage = Number(changedInput.dataset.percentage);
  
  const derivedInput = getOtherInput(changedInput);
  const derivedPercentage = Number(derivedInput.dataset.percentage);
  const derivedValue = definingValue / definingPercentage * derivedPercentage;
  derivedInput.value = derivedValue;
});

bar.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let firstPercentage = NaN;
  while (isNaN(parseInt(firstPercentage))) {
    firstPercentage = parseInt(prompt('Enter the percentage for the first input (less than 100, greater than 0, integer):'));
  }
  inputs[0].dataset.percentage = firstPercentage;
  inputs[1].dataset.percentage = 100 - firstPercentage;
})
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <label>This should consider as 90% for the input
<input type="number" data-percentage="90" placeholder="90%"></label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>This should consider as 10% for the input
<input type="number" data-percentage="10" placeholder="10%"></label>
</div>

<button type="button" id="bar">Change ratio</button>
```

When you click the button labeled "change ratio" it simply changes the `data-percentage` attributes, and the element behaviour updates automatically (still requires you to cause an input event to trigger in either input to update).